# onScroll() issue (executed three times)

Tags: android, listview, onscroll

In this code snippet, when scrolling comes to the end of list, method `Log.d()` executed 3 times. Why does it happen and how to detect end of list to execute method only once?

Snippet:

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isFavorites", false) == false) {
        try {
            if (visibleItemCount > 0 && firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Adding to list");

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `if` statement will execute as many times as the number of `visibleItemCount`. How many items do you see, 3?

Comment: Yes, 3. So, how to fix it to make it only once?

Comment: make operation when newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE condition meets. In that way, it will only execute once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement a `boolean` variable to ensure execution of the `if` statement only once.

```
boolean executed = false;
```

and

```
if(visibleItemCount > 0 
    && firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount 
    && !executed)
{
    executed = true;
}
```